# AsyncJS with a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I'm looking to do something fairly simple with Nodejs and Async.

I have a number of `pages`, say 4 for our example. And I want to make a request 4 times and then trigger a callback when they have all returned.

```
  async.eachSeries new Array(pages)
    ,(i,next)->
      offset+=100;
      next();
    ,(err)->
      console.log("All done!");
```

Is there an async method can I use a for loop in? Or do I need to loop over and create the functions first, and then pass to async?

Update: is the above the best way to do this?

Comment: what you mean with which method?

Comment: [async.times](https://github.com/caolan/async#times)

Comment: @AndreasHultgren that should be an answer and not a comment as it fully answers OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async.times(4, function(n, next){
    somethingAsync(n, next);
},
function (err) {
    // Here when all four calls are done
});
```

See [async.times](https://github.com/caolan/async#times).